# Использование папки с картинками вне сервера(на диске) WildFly

Tags: изображения, java-ee, jboss, wildfly

Использую папку на диске для хранения картинок пользователей 
(tmp/usr1/)
(tmp/usr2/)
Не могу найти настройки для WildFly, которые откроют для использования эту папку.

В Базе храню ссылку на картинку, но файл по хранимой ссылке можно открыть как `file:///...` 
Подскажите как настроить сервер через `joss-web.xml` или `standalone.xml`
или другие способы отображения через `JSF`

Пишу учебный проект - только разбираюсь с Java EE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавляем локацию /images, которая отображается на /tmp
Соответственно url картинок будут такого вида http://server:port/images/usr1/image1.png

В standalone.xml добавлены `<location name="/images" handler="images-content"/>` и соответствующий handler `<file name="images-content" path="/tmp"/>`

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:2.0">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <location name="/images" handler="images-content"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            </host>
        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config/>
            <websockets/>
        </servlet-container>
        <handlers>
            <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
            <file name="images-content" path="/tmp"/>
        </handlers>
        <filters>
            <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/9"/>
            <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
        </filters>
    </subsystem>
```

Важно. Такие картинки будут доступны всем. Т.е. usr1 может подсмотреть картинки usr2 и наоборот.
Если нужно скрывать друг от друга, то нужно совсем другое решение - Servlet.

Comment: `Sergey` Учебный проект - соц сеть но через сервлет, судя по всему правильней... Можно линк на пример ?

Comment: Такой сервлет сделать не сложно. Просто как копирование файла. Ещё эта тема много раз подымалась по крайней мере на аглицком стекеоверфлове. Там какие-то наброски можно найти.

Comment: @Eugene тут правильнее будет использовать права назначаемые пользователям

Comment: Спасибо господа, справился. Благодаря советам